# What is the reason for the result of my Flink code with partitionCustom and keyBy

Tags: apache-flink

I have following Flink code to experiment watermark. What I want to achieve is that `A` and `B` use different watermark by routing them to different partitions.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.Partitioner
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.{AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks, KeyedProcessFunction}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{StreamExecutionEnvironment, _}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

object Test{
  def to_milli(str: String) =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str).getTime

  def to_char(milli: Long) = {
    val date = if (milli <= 0) new Date(0) else new Date(milli)
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
  }

  val data = Seq(
    ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:11"),
    ("B", "2020-08-30 10:50:13"),
    ("B", "2020-08-30 10:50:04"),
    ("A", "2020-08-30 10:50:08")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration())
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.setParallelism(4)

    env.fromCollection(data).setParallelism(1).partitionCustom(new Partitioner[String] {
      override def partition(key: String, numPartitions: Int): Int = key.hashCode() % numPartitions
    }, e => e._1).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[(String, String)]() {
      var maxSeen = Long.MinValue

      override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: (String, String), extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
        val eventTime = to_milli(lastElement._2)
        if (eventTime > maxSeen) {
          maxSeen = eventTime
        }
        println(s"key: ${lastElement._1}, event time: ${to_char(eventTime)}, watermark: ${to_char(maxSeen - 4 * 1000)} ")
        new Watermark(maxSeen - 4 * 1000)
      }

      override def extractTimestamp(element: (String, String), previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = to_milli(element._2)

    }).setParallelism(2).keyBy(_._1).process(new KeyedProcessFunction[String, (String, String), (String, String)] {
      override def processElement(value: (String, String), ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[String, (String, String), (String, String)]#Context, out: Collector[(String, String)]): Unit = {
        val watermark = ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()
        val key = ctx.getCurrentKey
        val s = if (watermark == Long.MinValue) s"MIN_VALUE: $watermark" else to_char(watermark)
        System.out.println(s"watermark:$key is: $s ")
        val eventTime = value._2

        if (eventTime > to_char(watermark)) out.collect(value)
      }
    }).setParallelism(2).print()

    env.execute()


  }

}
```

When I run the above code, it prints:

```
key: B, event time: 2020-08-30 10:50:13, watermark: 2020-08-30 10:50:09 
key: A, event time: 2020-08-30 10:50:11, watermark: 2020-08-30 10:50:07 
key: B, event time: 2020-08-30 10:50:04, watermark: 2020-08-30 10:50:09 
key: A, event time: 2020-08-30 10:50:08, watermark: 2020-08-30 10:50:07 

watermark:A is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808 
watermark:B is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808 
watermark:A is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808 
watermark:B is: 2020-08-30 10:50:09 

3> (B,2020-08-30 10:50:13)
4> (A,2020-08-30 10:50:08)
3> (A,2020-08-30 10:50:11)
```

I just couldn't understand why it gives me:

```
watermark:B is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808 
watermark:A is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808 
watermark:B is: MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that since You are doing `keyBy` with parallelism, Flink will compute `Watermark` as `min` of Watermarks generated by all parallel streams.

So, in this case Watermarks generated by `A` won't always be visible to `B` and the timestamps generated by `B` won't be visible to `A`. It can even happen that for the program above all lines will print `-9223372036854775808`.

Note that `partitionCustom` doesn't do logical partitioning, so it's not the same thing as `keyBy` and it can still cause shuffle.

Comment: Thanks @dominik-wosiński for the explanation. To be honest, I don't quite understand.What do you mean by `Watermarks generated by A won't always be visible to B and the timestamps generated by B won't be visible to A.` Is it my code problem or Flink framwork's problem? I just want to see the correct behavior with some experiment code

Comment: There are two things here. First, Flink doesn't do per key Watermarking but global per operator instance. So, assume You have a 2 instances of one operator followed by a single instance of another operator. How is this operator supposed to know how to advance Watemarks? It just gets Watermark from both instances of previous operator and selects lower one. The same thing happens if You have shuffle or `keyBy` even if parallelism doesn't change. Docs explains this a little: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/concepts/time/#watermarks-in-parallel-streams

Comment: Thanks dominik-wosiński for the explanation. I need some while to understand and write some code to experiment and reason about the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the facts that lead to this outcome:

(1) The job topology is as follows: You have a single source task followed by a custom partitioner that sends the A and B events to 2 instances of the watermark generator, one handling the A events and the other handling the B events. This is followed by a hashed partitioner shuffling into 2 instances of the keyed process function.

(2) The way that punctuated watermark generators work is that the watermarks being created always follow the events that spawned their creation. (And fwiw, a watermark is only emitted if it is greater than the current watermark.) This explains why the process function is printing some lines with -9223372036854775808, because processElement is called before the operator processes the corresponding watermark.

(3) The current watermark for an operator with multiple inputs is the minimum of the most recently received watermarks from all of its input channels.

For a scenario that will print the MIN_VALUE exactly 3 times, consider this sequence:

- instance 1 of the process function processes an event A, producing a MIN_VALUE line
- instance 2 of the process function processes an event B, producing another MIN_VALUE line
- instance 1 processes the watermark that followed the A, and updates the watermark for channel A while leaving the watermark from channel B at MIN_VALUE
- instance 1 processes another A event. Its current watermark is still MIN_VALUE.
- instance 2 processes the watermark that followed the B event. At some point it also processes the watermark from channel A, after which its current watermark becomes 2020-08-30 10:50:09
- instance 2 process another B event and prints out its watermark, which is now 2020-08-30 10:50:09.

Note that the exact behavior is non-deterministic, because it depends on the race between the events and watermarks from the two different upstream operators. If the watermark from A arrived at instance 2 after the second B events, then a fourth MIN_VALUE would have been printed.